# Time as a Categorial Variable in a GLM and applying a trend analysis to the resulting Coefficients

Tags: time-series, generalized-linear-model

The technical question is: if you use time (years) as a categorical variable in a GLM to measure the effective of time (inflation) can you model the resulting coefficients to forecast into the future?  Here is an example to clarify the question.

Suppose you have some insurance contracts and you are looking at severity, the cost per claim. Another example would be the amount someone spends at a single visit to a store or restaurant. Suppose you fix a year for analysis, say 2015 (that is, all claims that occurred in 2015 with the additional caveat they the claims close very quickly so we can ignore development), and fit an lm or glm with log link, like log(mu) = beta1 x explantoryvariable1 +beta2 x explanatoryvariable2. I use a log link so coefficients can be interpreted multiplicatively. Suppose this model is a good fit - that you have found adequate predictors for average severity.

Now, suppose you enlarge to include claims from 2015 until the present, binning them into years and fit the same model adding in claim year as an explanatory variable, with 2015 as the base year.  Suppose this also results in a good fit.

You can use the results of the model to calculate an implied year-to-year percent change.  Suppose this shows a clear trend.  Does it make sense to apply a model for forecasting?

I understand that an alternative model would be to use time series from the start.  For example, if the explantoryvariable1 and  explantoryvariable2 were categorical you could separate the data into groups along these categories and just take the average severity (or spending amount) for each time period to get a time series which you could then analyze.  Using these method you would have more individual analyses to perform.

The GLM method I've described seems easier to interpret and provides a simpler high-level view because there is only 1 trend to look at.  That's why I'm curious if it is a valid method or to understand some pitfalls that may be involved.

Comment: It may be better to model the effect of time in a flexible nonlinear way (splines?) rather than the coefficients of a bunch of yearly coefficients.

Comment: To extrapolate into the future you'll be making a huge assumption that's possibly hard to justify. It's unlikely that time itself affects the outcome. As you say yourself, it's inflation. Are you comfortable extrapolating inflation (aka economic conditions) from the recent past into the next couple of years?